# variable checkout design on magento multisite with single checkout

Tags: magento

I'm running a magento multisite with a single checkout.  The sites are currently set up as stores and they're all using one secure url for checkout.

How do i get the checkout url to vary it's display of the design/format/logo ect, depending on which site the user is coming from?  Right now my checkout url retains only the default theme settings.

Answer (score 0):

Magento always executes within a single store context and therefore one theme configuration scope. You will need to adjust the theme calculation in `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package` to evaluate the store id in the quote object.

You can likely do this in an observer observing the checkout-related FullActionName `controller_action_predispatch_*` events in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()` and in your observer method doing something like the following:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->setTheme('theme');
```

This is a rough guide. YMMV.

Comment: your first sentence might give the answer that I needed.  What is a them configuration scope and how do i set it for each store context?

Comment: Best way to visualize is Admin > System > Configuration > Design. You can set design settings for each store scope via the dropdown at top left. Now, these settings are ultimately part of the config DOM structure. See `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getTheme()` for xpath.

Comment: for some reason "magento always executes within a single store context and therefore one theme configuration scope" is not working for me.  maybe i should clarify:  im running a multisite using "stores" and a single checkout on a separate unique domain.  how can i pass the store design onto the checkout url so that the user experience remains the same?  I mainly want the header/footer and logo to stay constant when the user goes from one of my stores to the checkout url, and i'd like that to happen regardless of what store they're coming from.  right now i cant even get the logo to stay

Comment: When the Magento app "runs" (see index.php - `Mage::run()`), its configuration is scoped to one single store scope, and therefore one set of theme configuration settings. Your requirement means that you need get around these settings and specify something else. It's not a terribly extensive customization, but it does touch on several esoteric aspects of the framework.